# Web API + CORS + Basic NTLM: 401 with Firefox + Chrome

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain

So I've been trolling every post I could find on this topic and still haven't figured it out. Hopefully you can help:

**Web API 2 with CORS enabled:**

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

**web.config:**

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Windows" /> 
</system.web>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("button").click(function()
    {
        var endpoint = "http://localhost:82/api/test";
        var base64Credentials = window.btoa("domain\credentials:password");

        $.ajax({
            url: endpoint,
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);
            },
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

**IIS has Basic Authentication enabled.**

**Basic Auth works in IE. Firefox and Chrome is subject to the preflight OPTIONS call.**

Using Fiddler, I can see that if I set IIS to allow both Anonymous and Basic Authentication then the OPTIONS call will result in a 200 and then the subsequent GET with Basic Auth kicks in and all is right in the world. If I turn off Anonymous, then I get 401 on the OPTIONS call.

**Question:**

Is it a requirement to allow both Anonymous and Basic authentication to support this use case?

Answer (score 1):

I've <strike>partially</strike> solved this on one of my projects.  <strike>It always works in IE, but in Chrome I still get random 401 replies on requests but when I examine the response web api is sending the JSON data back so it gets past the OPTIONS.</strike>

The IIS site config for Web API is:

- Windows Auth, anon disabled;
- And under Windows Auth providers (option on the right), move NTLM to the top

In your web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <!-- Allows auth in CORS AJAX requests -->
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    <!-- May only ever be one value - a domain or "*".  "*" is disallowed when Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is true -->
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:63415" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

and in Global.asax.cs

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        // When Chrome sends the OPTIONS it breaks on windows auth, so this fixes it.
        if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            Response.Flush();
        }
    }
```

All of that is without using the CORS NuGet package. I tried that but I still had the OPTIONS problems.

EDIT: An update on this, it all seems to be working perfectly well for me in Chrome now.